# Calling Activity method from FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create an android app which receives Firebase message from server and changes the source image of a ImageView by calling a function.

my firebase Service:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    MainActivity.changeUi(body);
}
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Loading Home Layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    iv=findViewById(R.id.imgView);
}
 public static void changeUi(String s){
    if(s=="change")
      iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
 }
}
```

The App Crashes on sending firebase message.
This is my first app and I could not understand other answers. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling static method will create new instance of that activity. Here its crashing due to imageView not initialize.

You can use BroadCast Receiver here. Below is an example.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent("FBR-IMAGE");
    myIntent.putExtra("action",body);
    this.sendBroadcast(myIntent);
}
```

On Activity you need to create and register receiver

```
public BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getStringExtra("action");
        changeUi(action);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("FBR-IMAGE"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Calling a function of activity from anywhere is not a good idea even though the function is static. Activity instance is tightly coupled with android os and you will loose the reference as soon you os will release the activity reference. Also you cannot create a new instance of any activity by using `new` keyword.

Here you can use a broadcast receiver, you can a broadcast receiver and register it to the activity and broadcast from firebase. I hope this will works for you.

Another solution is handler as well but I found that broadcast receiver is much good option.